# How to send UDP packet from Debian 9 CRON?

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying with these 2 scripts:

**test1,sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +"NOW;%Y;%m;%d;%H;%M;%S")
echo -n $NOW | nc -u -q 2 -w 2 192.168.0.252 4210
```

**test2.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +'NOW;%Y;%m;%d;%H;%M;%S')
echo -n $NOW > /dev/udp/192.168.0.252/4210
```

Both scripts works fine when directly execute on terminal, client successfully receiving the UDP packets.

```
*/5 * * * * root /etc/test/test1.sh
*/5 * * * * root /etc/test/test2.sh
```

But doesn't work when executing in CRON, client did not receive the UDP packets.

```
**sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog**
Mar 10 16:40:01 localhost CRON[12281]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Mar 10 16:40:01 localhost CRON[12286]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Mar 10 16:40:01 localhost CRON[12287]: (root) CMD (root /etc/test/test1.sh)
Mar 10 16:40:01 localhost CRON[12289]: (root) CMD (root /etc/test/test2.sh)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the next to last block the output of `crontab -l`? Looks to me like there's an extra "root" in there.

The hint is in your syslog output:

```
Mar 10 16:40:01 localhost CRON[12289]: (root) CMD (root /etc/test/test2.sh)
```

Remove the `root` from your crontab and you'll have better luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works perfectly after removing ```root```

Comment: The new crontab:
```*/5 * * * * /etc/test/test1.sh```
```*/5 * * * * /etc/test/test2.sh```
and it works.... once again, thank you